# How to get system color in python?

Tags: python, colors

[To get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0MJc.png).     How to get the color/appearance in python. For example if the user is using system wide dark theme or light theme? Thanks in advance.

Comment: little context please. what system?

Comment: I have added the setting detail for the user here. I want to know if the system uses dark or light theme in his desktop , so that I could use the same theme for my app.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `darkdetect` module for that. It works on both Windows and macOS.
`pip install darkdetect`

Now, to show how it works:

```
import darkdetect

if darkdetect.isDark():
    print("Dark mode is enabled.")
else:
    print("Dark mode is not enabled.")
```

More information on `darkdetect` [here](https://pypi.org/project/darkdetect/).

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import system
command = 'theme=$(defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle) && if [[ $theme == "Dark" ]]; then python3 -c "from color import ifdark; ifdark()"; else python3 -c "from color import iflight; iflight()"; fi'
theme = system(command)
```

The `defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle` will return "Dark" if the theme is dark, and a user specific message if not.

Comment: The dark is printed and is not returned in the following method. any work around that?

Comment: This is a little messy, but it should work. You will have to have a separate file with the two functions for whether the theme is light or not though.