# Find if theme is dark or light in windows 10 using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, darkmode

Is there any way to find if system has dark or light theme in windows 10?
Has windows provided any api which will detect the theme using win32api that is usable from python 2.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get system color in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156048/how-to-get-system-color-in-python)

Comment: Yes, I used the reading registry approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an answer for this on [How to get system color in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156048/how-to-get-system-color-in-python)

And perhaps [Detect OS dark mode in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65294987/detect-os-dark-mode-in-python) might be useful too.

Comment: Thanks for finding those +1. I flagged the question as a duplicate. When you get more xp, you will be able to do the same. It really helps out the site.